# Having fits with a formula which includes a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to put a SUMIF formula into a cell but it returns a weird result.
BottomRow winds up being the last row in a table.  When I run the macro and look at the value of txtformula in the immediate window I get =Sumif(B6:B241,F6:F19,D6:D241)
when it goes in the cell it enters =SUMIF(B6:B241,@F6:F19,D6:D241)

Where is the darn @ sign coming from?

```
Range("B6").End(xlDown).Select
Classbottom = ActiveCell.Address
BottomRow = Range(Classbottom).Row

'Create totals data
Range("G6").Activate
txtFormula = "=Sumif(B6:B" & BottomRow & ",F6:F19,D6:D" & BottomRow & ")"
ActiveCell.Formula = txtFormula
```

Comment: Criteria range and sum range must be same. You have fixed criteria range `F6:F19` while sum range is variable.

Comment: Re _Where is the darn @ sign coming from?_ Use `ActiveCell.Formula2 = txtFormula`.  [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2)

Answer (score 0):

I guessed at trying a different formula.  I did

activecell.formula2 = txtFormula

It did the trick

Comment: Maybe you can use ```Range("G6").formula2 = txtFormula``` without the need to activate that cell? I would also consider defining which Worksheet the code is referring to, for example ```ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("edit-name-to-suit").Range("G6").formula2 = txtFormula```. Also, does the formula need to refer to  ```BottomRow ``` in Column F?

Comment: Hi Andrew.  The problem is the range changes.   Yes it needs to refer to bottom row as the number of rows changes so I have to find the bottom then use it in the formula.   Formula2 did the trick.